# playing mp3 of a certain event is occured

Tags: java, audio, wav, playback

When I read a mp3(.wav) file to my application it raises an error

Code:

```
final String RESOURCE_LOCATION = "D:/capture.wav";
try {
    //AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(BillForm.class.getResource(RESOURCE_LOCATION));
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(RESOURCE_LOCATION));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The error is:

> javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.

Comment: Seems that the format is not supported, Try with Another File, and Lets check What Happens

Comment: Check the Answer of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887756/error-while-playing-sound-in-java/21888037#21888037) Question, That may Help You

Comment: format mean, u are saying to change the wav to another one? or another  file?

Comment: No, i mean another file, there are different rates of frequencies, in your current file it is 480000, Check on another file, and visit the Question above to have a clear idea. wav is supported , but the frequesncies matter

Comment: i checked with another two wav files,but still it arises that error, may we need to change the bit rate of that file manually? does it help?

Comment: Whether they Are of the same rate?

Comment: yes .. that side all of wav files are same bit rate but different size.

Comment: mp3 is not wav. why are you talking about mp3 in this question, if you use a wav file? which is it?

Comment: no no i used wav type of file not mp3

Comment: k Ahamed nw prblm is solved by reducing the bit rate.